# Java - saving JPanel as an image

Tags: java, jpanel, bufferedimage

I've got a popular problem. I've read a lot about it, but I still can't solve it. I'm coding something like MSW Logo (Turtle graphics interpreter) and I want to save my image (drawn on class extending JPanel). The problem is that saved image is blank (only white background, nothing more, no shapes).

From posts on StackOverflow I noticed, that drawing on JPanel is wrong and I should draw on BufferedImage, but I don't know how to apply this tip to my source code. Please, help me get off the ground. Thanks a lot! :)

My class extending JPanel:

```
public class TurtlePanel extends JPanel {

    public TurtlePanel() {
        super();
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(481, 481));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }

}
```

Creating the panel:

```
public class PanelView {

    private JPanel panel;
    private MainWindowView mainView;


    public PanelView(MainWindowView mainView) {
        this.mainView = mainView;
        createView();
    }

    private void createView() {
        panel = new TurtlePanel();
        panel.setBounds(280, 30, 481, 481);
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panel.setVisible(true);
        mainView.mainWindow.add(panel);
    }

    public JPanel getPanel() {
        return this.panel;
    }

}
```

The way I'm drawing shapes (it works, shapes are displaying on my panel):

```
private void drawCircle(double radius) {
    if(Math.signum(radius) == -1)
        throw new NumberFormatException();

    if(turtleModel.isShown()) {
        Graphics2D g = ((Graphics2D) panelView.getPanel().getGraphics());
        g.setColor(turtleModel.getPenColor());
        g.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(turtleModel.getPosX() - radius, turtleModel.getPosY() - radius, 2*radius, 2*radius));
    }
}
```

The way I'm trying to save my image:

```
try {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(panelView.getPanel().getWidth(), panelView.getPanel().getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics graphics = image.getGraphics();
    panelView.getPanel().paint(graphics);
    ImageIO.write(image, ext, new File(path));
} 
catch(IOException exc) {
    exc.printStackTrace();
}
```

Again, thank You for help! If You need additional information, let me know. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling **paint(graphics)** will not copy the content of your current panel.
That's not really the way it's supposed to be working.

Normally, you add swing components to a JPanel, and calling **paintComponents()** would call **paint()** of every components contained in your JPanel.

You should not be drawing directly, instead you could modify TurtlePanel so it own a list of the actions he must do to a Graphics object, and override it's paint() method so it can always print it's entire content from a fresh new Graphics object.

Obviously, for a professional architecture, you might think of a better approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I probably know how to fix my drawing.

Answer (score 0):

Drawing on a JPanel is perfectly fine. If you redraw often, and those redraws draw the same thing, then that is when you may want to cache your graphics in a BufferedImage.

I am unsure how your current rendering is done, as it seems to operate on a Graphics object that may be an instance variable, which is odd, because you don't want to save off those Graphics objects. Having a nonstandard (probably broken) way to paint your graphics is what is giving you trouble most likely.

The simplistic way to fix this is to create a more abstract method that draws what you wish to render on a Graphics object that is passed in. Then, both the JPanel's paintComponent method (use the Graphics object from that), and the code about saving the image (the Graphics object from the image) can both call the share the same method.

Comment: Thank You! You're right - my way to paint is broken.